# zip files without including parent directories

Tags: r, zip

When I run this

```
zip('C:\\path\\to\\dir\\out'
    , files = paste0('C:\\path\\to\\dir\\', c('one.xlsx', 'two.xlsx')))
```

it zips the files, but unzipping them gives a folder that contains the "path" folder, which contains the "to" folder, etc (the full directory path). So after unzipping, the files are now in `C:\\path\\to\\dir\\out\\path\\to\\dir\\`.

How can I zip the files without the resulting zip file containing all the parent directories?

I'm using Windows 10

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.2                         
year           2017                        
month          09                          
day            28                          
svn rev        73368                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
nickname       Short Summer
```

Comment: Ryan, perhaps you can use `withr::with_dir("/path/to/dir", zip("out.zip", c("one.xlsx","two.xlsx")))`, where the `with_dir` is just temporarily setting the working directory for the call to `zip`.

Comment: but you have included two paths, ie you should do `zip('C:\\path\\to\\dir\\out'
    , files =  c('one.xlsx', 'two.xlsx'))`

Comment: I agree with Onyambu. An alternative approach would be to include a 'j' flag in the flags parameter to drop the paths, i.e. include `flags = '-r9Xj'` as a parameter in the zip call.

Comment: @icj, the flags option worked. Feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: @icj, where can I learn more bout these flags?

Comment: @Ryan, see answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.1/topics/zip), the R zip function's utilizes `R_ZIPCMD`, which is set in `etc/Rcmd_environ`. This is set to the command line `zip` windows utility by default. The R function provides the input parameter *flags* to pass additional input parameters to the underlying command line zip function. The manual which describes 
flags can be downloaded [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm).

The `-j` flag allows just the file names to be stored rather than the full file path.

```
f_path <- 'C:\\path\\to\\dir\\out'
zip(f_path,
    files = paste0(f_path, c('one.xlsx', 'two.xlsx')),
    flags = '-r9Xj')
```

The `-r9X` portion of the flags input are the default parameters passed to underlying utility function and specify that the zip command should recursively search sub-directories, use maximum compression, and remove depreciated file fields.

This has only been tested using the windows zip utility. The necessary flag(s) may differ when using the unix utility.